# Can I sneak in an std::vector as a FILE* when calling C functions in C++11?

Tags: c, file, c++11, file-io, vector

What about using an `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` as a `FILE*` argument when invoking a C function that expects to receive a pointer to a file ?

Personally I can't recall any object or element from the standard library that can be used as a C style file.

Why I want to do this:

- get out the user space as soon as possible, so I quickly load everything into a vector
- "centralize" memory management, since I use vectors a lot, I just use yet another vector for dealing with files
- simplifies algorithms and functions, because of basically the same reasons as my previous point

Comment: Are you kidding? Do you really think a `FILE*` points directly to the data in the file? It's an opaque struct that let's you access the file *somehow*. There's no way to swap it with a vector and have your program behave the same. Another issue is that a `vector` contains a pointer to the data it owns as well, so your C function will have no idea how to go about accessing that even if `FILE*` did really point to the file data.

Comment: @Praetorian what makes you think that ?

Comment: why not using C++ file handling?

Comment: @Praetorian by the way I just a couple of ideas, but I'm not sure about that, for example using `data()`.

Comment: @G.Samaras I have a nice library with really nice memory management for std::vector/std::allocators, and since I need to use a parser/lexer with this files, I need to do something that will be somehow memory-centric. C++ file handling doesn't really offer anything special.

Comment: you should motivate why is a bad idea by the way, I don't really understand what the cons are .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a very limited sense, you can do it for reading only by using the [`fmemopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) function <sup>*</sup>.

- Instantiate a `vector`
- Fill the vector with data as needed
- Call `fmemopen`, passing it `vect.data()`, `vect.size()`, and the `"r"` flag
- Use the resultant `FILE *` to pass to functions that need to read from a file.

<sup>*</sup> It does not mean that it is worth doing it in this way, though.

Comment: what are the possible downsides ?

Comment: @user2485710 The main problem is that the buffer would go away as soon as the `vector` is deallocated, without letting the `FILE*` know that it's no longer acceptable to read from that memory. If you can organize your code in such a way that it stops accessing the `FILE*` before the `vector` is deallocated, there should be no issues with this approach.

Comment: right, in this mix I forgot that RAII it's not exactly a `C` thing, so I should manage the lifetime of the object. It's strange that no one is mentioning http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer to be used as a pointer to the `char` sequence.

Comment: @user2485710 That's because `get_temporary_buffer` is there for a different purpose - you use it for making temporary storage, usually within the scope of a single execution block (e.g. a function). In conjunction with `fmemopen` it could replace a `vector` in your example.

Comment: yep, the only problem is that this `get_temporary_buffer` apparently doesn't accepts a custom allocator, and allocations and memory efficiency is the reason I was trying to use my `vector` in the first place. Doesn't look like `C++` functions are designed to really interact with C functions. I think I'll benchmark this.

Answer (score 4):

On some platforms, the standard library contains functions, which can be used for that purpose. For example, on Linux the following two functions are available:

- [fmemopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html): Create a `FILE*` from a char buffer.
- [fopencookie](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html): Create a `FILE*` with custom functions.

According to the linked man pages, **fmemopen** is part of POSIX-2008 and **fopencookie** is a GNU extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not - functions like `fprintf` expect to be able to dereference that `FILE*` and get a `FILE`, and a `std::vector` is definitely not a `FILE`.  In glibc, a `FILE` is a typedef for something like this:

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;           /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A `FILE *` and a `std::vector<char> *` are two different types that are not directly compatible.

An easy example of this is that a `std::vector` store in memory all of the data that the object uses. A `FILE *`, on the other hand, has a opaque integer that allows a function to request more data from the operating system.

So, if you were to do:

```
std::string get_line(FILE *) { ... }
```

And you called it as:

```
std::vector<char> v
std::string s = get_line((FILE *) &v);
```

I would expect your application to exhibit a large pile of undefined behavior.

Comment: yes, I was expecting something like that due to the different nature of this 2 types, but assuming that a `FILE*` doesn't access "extra" information from the filesystem, what about walking down this path.

Comment: @user2485710: What _"extra"_ information are you referring to?

Comment: anything that will cause the _undefined behavior_ that you are mentioning in your post.

Comment: So that's not "extra" information, that's __all__ of the information. Accessing anything about that vector (which is cast as a FILE *) will cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from your description, it seems like you want something that can be accessed either as a block of memory or as a (C-style) file stream; if so, it may be that, rather than multiple round-trips into a vector<> type, you might be better off using a **memory mapped** file in parallel with a shared-mode `FILE*`.

It's been a while since I had need to do this, but it looks like there's a [nice, lightweight library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmstream/) on SourceForge called `fmstream`, which gives you a C++ wrapper (the latest source seems to include C++11 features; I would check to make sure that the released version does as well) called `fmstream`. (Also, `ifmstream`, for the read-only version.)

To use a memory mapped file, you will instantiate by opening it with the aforementioned class. This (I am assuming) will be an OS-level memory-mapping of the file; and, indeed, this gives you 'direct' (at least from your code's point of view) access to the file. There are a number of different modes for this, but basically it's just using your file as a section of virtual memory. Thus, should you make changes to the file, you are actually changing the file on disk, too—the lazy case being when the changes to the file are not written until you close the file, or command it to; but there should be immediate modes that keep the data more or less in-sync as you change the memory.

Not sure if writes are a specific part of your use-case, but using a map may still be advantageous, or not, even if you aren't doing any writing. The best way to tell is to do some prototyping using some data files that come as close as possible to replicating the types of load you'll have in processing a real file, and doing some performance testing. For the read-write case, you can use `fmstream` for a more performant read-only stream you can use `ifmstream`.

Anyhow, at the point you need a data pointer, you'll just call `data()` method on an instance of one of the streams, and access it as a large block of memory; and, as a memory-mapped file, it (should) lazy load the data as it's needed (remember it's an OS structure, that's just being manipulated in C++; so, most of the underlying stuff should be about as optimized as it could reasonably be for a general case) and not require loading a mass of stuff all at once.

For the C functions, you can just use the memory-mapped file in tandem with using a C `FILE*`, opened in shared mode, directly with your C functions; and, in fact, you can linkly just include the headers in an `extern "C" { /* includes */ }` block and link to the object code directly, assuming it's a static C library.

Once you're done with the file, all you'll have to do is clean up the stream (or let it automatically do so by using something like `unique_pointer` to instantiate it in the first place, so that scoping takes care of it.) If you're doing a lot of reads you might want to open it, save it somewhere, and close it later; if you're doing all your processing at once you might just want to open and close it in a function that wraps the functionality.

Hopefully that gives you more-or-less what you needed, without a lot of extra work (although I do recommend you do a bit of reading for you particular platform on how the memory mapping works at an OS level, so you don't get bitten by something working differently than you expected.)

CAVEAT: I haven't looked too closely at this specific implementation, and, as I say, it's been a while since I used this technique, but I assume things haven't changed that much. If you run into issues, or need some clarification; let me know and I'll try to find some time to dig a little further...